# Lightweight Linux for Mobile phones?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, lenovo, android, phone

(Linux noob here running Lubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 32-bit) Recently, I brought back my old netbook to life by installing Lubuntu.(Currently daily driving it due to quarantine 'cause my main laptop broke.)I have an old phone lying around named Lenovo A-6000 with 1GB RAM running Android KitKat (terribly slow). I want to repurpose it to be used by my son for learning (again... due to quarantine). I want it to make calls and open 2 chrome tabs at once and run smoothly. Is there any lightweight linux distro for mobile devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some [projects](https://itsfoss.com/open-source-alternatives-android/) out there, but the general answer is no.
The main problem is that most mobile drivers are closed source and only available for certain versions of Android. So they cannot be used by other systems and of course reverse-engineering them is not easy (and/or can cause legal issues). The mentioned projects are usually focused on a subset of models, but even they cannot guarantee flawless working for every component.